Error 'recompile with -fPIC' during building parallel HDF5
I tried to build parallel HDF5 following its install instruction.
I built building directory, and commanded
$ ../hdf5-source/configure --enable-parallel CC=mpicc
$ make

to build parallel hdf5, and I got below error message.
/usr/bin/ld: /HOME/USER/apps/mpich-3.3.2/lib/libmpi.a(lib_libmpi_la-comm_create_keyval.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `MPII_Attr_copy_c_proxy' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/HOME/USER/apps/mpich-3.3.2/lib/libmpi.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libhdf5.la] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

I understood that I have to set CFLAGS=-fPIC & CXXFLAGS=-fPIC in configuring process, so I tried to command like below.
$ ../hdf5-source/configure --enable-parallel CC=mpicc CFLAGS=-fPIC CXXFLAGS=-fPIC
$ make

However I got same error as above.
What is problem and how can it be solved?
